# Typescript deduce return type of member function of generic type

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I have something I'm trying to do but I'm not quite sure how to achieve it in typescript.

I'm working with discord.js and I'm trying to make a wrapper to convert `Discord.User | Discord.PartialUser` (or similar `T | PartialT` types) to their non-partial versions.

Something like this:

```
interface Partial {
    partial: boolean;
    fetch(): Promise<any>;
}
async function departialize<T extends Partial>(thing: T) {
    if(thing.partial) {
        return await thing.fetch();
    } else {
        return thing;
    }
}
```

While this compiles, I would like to include more type information. I.e. with this example I would like it to return `Promise<Discord.User>` instead of `Promise<Any>`.

Both `Discord.User.fetch()` and `Discord.PartialUser.fetch()` return `Promise<Discord.User>`, can this be deduced in the interface or return type? In C++ we would write something like `decltype(std::declval<T>().fetch())`, not sure what to do in TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, here's what I'm going with in case it helps anyone else:

```
type PotentiallyPartial = Discord.AllowedPartial | Discord.Partialize<Discord.AllowedPartial>;

async function departialize<T extends PotentiallyPartial, R extends ReturnType<T["fetch"]>>(thing: T): Promise<R> {
    if(thing.partial) {
        return thing.fetch();
    } else {
        return thing as R;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overloaded function which will provide a correct return type for your input, narrowing based on the inferred value of the `partial` property.

> Notes:
>
> - Because the [`Partial` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) is already declared in TypeScript, I've used the type name `Incomplete` to avoid a compiler error.
> - `unknown` is more type safe than `any`, but feel free to replace if you really need `any`.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ssl=37&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgQewLYAcA2EkAPACrIC8yAriANYiYDuIAfMgN4CwAUMsrjhQwwOPgBcyAEaZMhOCADcvfjCIIAFsgAUASkkAFKDmABnCGVbKeAX168YtBCMwhkAEwiDho-MABeKGTIEAAekCDupmgYOAREKABknAJCImKSYFDUKDas2mAaoADmkqT6yABKRNRQIKQAnrgWpADaAORqYJrtALpWDk4ubp7e6X6ByMFhEVExWHiEkMjJHKk+Gcjw+ObIeQVFIKXI5WXWjhjDHl5pvgFB5DMQkdHoC-GQ+YUlZRXkAD5VGp1RrNMgdLo9frnIbAVzXMZ3SbTcLPOZvOJLCBfQ7HU4nZCA6pgWr1JotCHqDR9djcPjIKDAtzfI4AOkRYmQAH5kCziqzIRo9Mg4NFiaTQRTOlSachMrjrHYeLwAPQq5AAVVMcGKEHE9h4ngQ+CEKCwIFMYGQoFw1DAAEZJHT+ByJNJZPIlCotlSdBUjCZzMRLVASgN6aYcBAAPKFaAB3CSEDUbBSaCK6y8c2W5CYO22h2UBG3MT3bQ2u323SKZBq3nkzAwa0gAv2wnIAPYMwWENhg1Gk2M5DZq0VsAAJid3tdmWyEGsql9ekMxi7Qd7R3D-Ej2BjcagCaTKbTUAzBpHufzdvHRdGJYmEHLLev1dr6s73eDWT7ysNEGNprDq4OZjgAzFO9IzlsYjmAuPrdFoy4dqun4bsUW7IDue4aPGxiJsgyapumvA2JmPAXnmYAFqBt43BsD5PtRr51mADZNmBvBAA)

```ts
interface Incomplete<T = unknown> {
  partial: boolean;
  fetch (): Promise<T>;
}

function departialize <T extends Incomplete & { partial: true }>(thing: T): ReturnType<T['fetch']>;
function departialize <T extends Incomplete & { partial: false }>(thing: T): T;
function departialize <T extends Incomplete>(thing: T): T | ReturnType<T['fetch']>;
function departialize <T extends Incomplete>(thing: T): T | ReturnType<T['fetch']> {
  return thing.partial ? thing.fetch() as ReturnType<T['fetch']> : thing;
}

// Usage:

declare const input1: {
  partial: boolean;
  fetch (): Promise<string>;
  someOtherProp: number;
};

const output1 = departialize(input1); // typeof input1 | Promise<string>

declare const input2: {
  partial: true;
  fetch (): Promise<string>;
  someOtherProp: number;
};

const output2 = departialize(input2); // Promise<string>

declare const input3: {
  partial: false;
  fetch (): Promise<string>;
  someOtherProp: number;
};

const output3 = departialize(input3); // typeof input3
```